# Java : Combine several completable futures in a chain

Tags: java, completable-future

I'd like to have a method to send a request and then receive a response over UDP.
Here is what I've developed for the moment :

```
public <T extends ObjectSerializable, U extends ObjectDeserializable>
CompletableFuture<Object> execute(T request, U response)
{
    var resultFuture = sender.asyncSend(request); /*CompletableFuture<Void>*/
    resultFuture.thenAccept((nullObj) -> {
        try {
            receiver.asyncReceive(response).get(); /*CompletableFuture<Void>*/
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new FutureExecutionException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }).thenRun(()  -> {
        System.out.println("Send->Receive finished");
    });

    return resultFuture;
}
```

The question is : do I have to wait for the future inside `.thenAccept` ? Is it guaranteed that `.thenRun` will be executed after receiver.asyncReceive would finish?
Am I doing the right way combining CompletableFutures like this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that looks fine

```
public <T extends ObjectSerializable, U extends ObjectDeserializable>
CompletableFuture<Void> execute(T request, U response)
{
    return sender.asyncSend(request)
            .thenCompose( result -> receiver.asyncReceive(response))
            .thenRun( () -> System.out.println("Send-Receive finished"));
}
```

Comment: _I'd like to have a method to send a request and then receive a response over UDP_, but here you return a `CompletableFuture<Void>` that you have no idea if it is completed or not. is that what you want?

Comment: yes, because later on I simple call .get and retrieve response object. In case of timeout I get ExecutionException. If you are interested in a full source code, I can share it to you directly.

Comment: what response object? you will get a void on calling the blocking `get`. Also, then the method name makes no sense, it is not `execute`ing anything, potentially. It _could_ execute, but only when `sender.asyncSend(request)` is ready before `.thenCompose( result -> receiver.asyncReceive(response))` has been appended to the previous future.

Comment: .get gives me a guarantee that response object has already been deserialized inside the receiver and I can safely access it. As far as I understood, thenCompose will execute only if the previous future was ok, am I wrong? At least my tests show this behavior

Comment: you have a lot of context that I do not. It is very weird how you have the `response` as an argument on the `execute` method, as opposed to the return type... it seems your `receiver.asyncReceive(response)` is storing the response somewhere, so when you later call `get` and it succeeded, you get the response from "somewhere". no?

Comment: Well, you are right, that response should have been returned inside the future...but I don’t know the way to create an object out of its type in Java. That’s why I pass a default constructed response object which is filled inside the async call. So, I must create a response object, than call execute, than .get and finally I get it right. Any ideas to improve this solution ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224497/discussion-between-eugene-and-dmitry).

Answer (score 0):

This would be a lot easier if your `execute` would take a `Class<U>` as argument. Then you could pass that class to `receiver.asyncReceive`. Internally, you could (assuming such a class has a default constructor) create an instance and populate it with all the fields. This is rather easy via :

```
clazz.getConstructor().newInstance()
```

Then your code would return a `CompletableFuture<Response>`, so your method would become something like:

```
    public <T extends ObjectSerializable, U extends ObjectDeserializable>
              CompletableFuture<U> execute(T request, Class<U> response){
         return sender.asyncSend(request)
                      .thenCompose(nothing -> receiver.asyncReceive(response));
    }
```

I am also not sure your `asyncSend` is supposed to return a `CompletableFuture<Void>` either, may be this one can take a `Class<U>` as a parameter too and return the proper type as `CompletableFuture<U>`, but then you do not need `asyncReceive`, I guess...